# How would constructor will be called in this code?

Tags: c++, constructor

How would constructor be call in this code ?

Neither `x()` is called nor `x(int i = 0)` is called in this code. Could not make how the constructor is being called.

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class x
{
int value;
public:
    x(){
        value = 0;
        cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
    }

    x(int i = 0){
        value = i;
        cout<<"Bye"<<endl;
    }

};

int main(){
    x a();
    return 0 ;
}
```

Output is neither "Hello" nor "Bye".

Comment: This `x a();` is a function declaration or 'most vexing parse' this is why your ctor is never called

Comment: @EdChum: This is not the most vexing parse. I like to call it the lesser vexing parse as a compromise.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Literally a different question (indeed, the fact asked about _here_ is part of the premise of the question _there_)